# Return multiple parameters from a function using if else in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm facing an error while trying to return multiple parameters from a function using if else in Jenkins pipeline script. Below is my test pipeline.

```
def envi, host

def build_func(envi, host){
  if (env.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev') {
    envi = 'dev'
    host = 'devhost'
  }
  else if(env.ENVIRONMENT == 'prod') {
    envi = 'prod'
    host = 'prodhost'
  }
  return [envi, host]
}

pipeline {
agent any
environment {
  def (envir,hostname) = build_func(env,host)
}

stages {
  stage('Hello') {
    steps {
      echo "Hello World\n${envir}\n${env.ENVIRONMENT}"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

When I build this, getting the below error,

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
> WorkflowScript: 18: Expected string literal @ line 18, column 7.
> def (envir,hostname) = build_func(env,host)

Comment: The error is currently absent from the question.

Comment: @MattSchuchard updated the question with the error which I've faced from Jenkins build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can return multiple values and create Environment variables like that within an `environment` block. As a workaround, maybe you can do something like this.

```
environment {
  envir = "${build_func(env,host)[0]}"
  hostname = "${build_func(env,host)[1]}"
}
```